# Is it possible to set the shape of an interface when you don't know the size of the input (but do know the types the keys-and-values will be?)

Tags: typescript

I am trying to see if I can setup an interface to type check my code. I have an object that I am filling up with an array (that comes from parameters). I loop through the array and add the key-value pairs both as the value from the array. I am a newbie to TS, so I would appreciate some help as I couldn't find this information (even in the video I watched to learn it nor on their website docs.)

Here is the code for clarity sake

```
     export function example(array: number[], targetSum: number): number[] {
      // I want to setup a interface here named Hash and shape it with the values of the array being both the key and value pair.
      const hash: object = {};
      for(let i: number = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        hash[array[i]] = array[i];
      }
      return [];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
interface Hash {
    [key: string]: number;
}

export function example(array: number[], targetSum: number): number[] {
  // I want to setup a interface here named Hash and shape it with the values of the array being both the key and value pair.
  const hash: Hash = {};
  for (let i: number = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    hash[array[i]] = array[i];
  }
  return [];
}
```

an alternative for forming the `hash` object:

```
export function example(array: number[], targetSum: number): number[] {
  const hash: Hash = array.reduce((acc, cur) => ((acc[cur] = cur), acc), {});
  return [];
}
```